# Uso de mayúsculas en los siglos XVII y XVIII

Tags: historia, ortografía, uso-de-mayúsculas

Tras mucho tiempo consultando con frecuencia el *Autoridades* del siglo XVIII, primer diccionario que compuso la RAE, me he dado cuenta de que el citado diccionario hace un uso de las mayúsculas bastante más amplio que el actual, e incluso que el de otras obras cercanas.

Pongo un ejemplo:

[image: Mayúsculas en el Autoridades]

Por lo que veo, se usan mayúsculas:

- en referencias a idiomas ("voz Latina"),
- en referencias a palabras citadas metalingüísticamente, que se pueden consultar en el diccionario para más información ("que aunque significa la Choza ò Casa pajiza"), y
- en referencia a personas o agrupaciones de estas ("muros de las Ciudades, Villas y Lugáres de nuestros Réinos").

También me fijo en que en el *Covarrubias* de 1611 se da también:

[image: Mayúsculas en el Covarrubias]

Aquí podemos ver más referencias a las mayúsculas en idiomas ("Castellano", "Lat."), en palabras citadas metalingüísticamente ("Ome") y en determinados grupos de personas ("Gentiles").

En otras obras de la época, como la edición [prínceps](https://dle.rae.es/?id=UBkBhZy) del Quijote, veo también uso de mayúsculas en algunos títulos, como "el Cura de su lugar", y en los días de la semana ("duelos y quebrantos los Sabados, lantejas los Viernes").

Algunos de estos usos se realizan hoy usando las cursivas, como los usos metalingüísticos de palabras. En el siglo XVII ya se usaba la letra cursiva, aunque sobre todo para las citas literales, y no se usaba para este menester.

Así pues, pregunto:

- ¿Cuáles eran las normas que regían en los siglos XVII y XVIII con respecto al uso de las mayúsculas a principio de palabra, que difieran de las actuales?
- Bonus: ¿Cuándo se abandonaron estos usos y se pasaron a los actuales?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consultando a un par de personas que se especializan en la literatura del Siglo de Oro, me apuntaron a trabajos de [Fidel Sebastián Mediavilla](https://dialnet.unirioja.es/servlet/autor?codigo=1128647), de la Universitat Autònoma de Barcelona, que estudió la puntuación y la ortografía de muchas obras del período. No he podido conseguir muchas de ellas, naturalmente, pero sí leer un par de trabajos en línea. Cito:

> Por lo común, un escritor de nuestro Siglo de Oro no prestaba mayor
>   atención a la ortografía con que se habían de imprimir sus textos.
>   Contaba con que era competencia del personal de la imprenta
>   (corrector, amanuense, cajistas), del mismo modo que hoy, por lo
>   común, se deja a su buen entender la tipografía. Había casos
>   excepcionales (...). Pero, aunque se tuviera especial empeño en ello,
>   si no se estaba muy encima del proceso de confección del impreso, el
>   criterio que prevalecía era el de cada imprenta.

Dice también que se usaba mayúscula después de los dos puntos cuando servían para dar paso a una cita (no había comillas), e incluso cuando seguía discurso indirecto. También aparecían las mayúsculas al comienzo de cada línea de verso, lo cual hacía que algunos copistas o imprenteros, confundidos, insertaran un punto y aparte antes, cortando así la oración.

[Carlos Mata Indurain](https://twitter.com/cmatain), de la Universidad de Navarra y el Instituto de Estudios Auriseculares, [dice](https://twitter.com/cmatain/status/1134094767430799360):

> Sin haber estudiado el tema, mi idea sobre los textos del XVII es que
>   no había reglas fijas a la hora de puntuar, y tampoco sobre el uso de
>   mayúsculas y minúsculas. La cosa quedaba al criterio de cada autor,
>   pero también de los copistas, tipógrafos, etc.

Sobre las mayúsculas, [constata](https://twitter.com/cmatain/status/1134095264833331200) lo ya visto:

> Y, efectivamente, basta con leer cualquier texto impreso en el XVII
>   para darse cuenta de que había cierta tendencia a la "mayusculitis".
>   Cualquier palabra considerada especialmente significativa (Rey,
>   Monarca, Fe, Religión, etc.) suele ir en mayúscula, pero no solo
>   esas...
>
> Los gentilicios y etnónimos también suelen ir en mayúsculas: Francés,
>   Portugués, Gitano, Hebreo... Y los nombres de elementos de la
>   naturaleza: Sol, Luna... Y los meses del año: Enero, Febrero...
>
> En el caso de los manuscritos, el copista puede poner en mayúscula
>   cualquier palabra que a él le parezca relevante o significativa, sin
>   ningún criterio especial más allá de su gusto personal... Y a la
>   inversa, es frecuente encontrar con minúscula nombres propios: juan,
>   dios...

Por todo esto parece que en realidad la norma es que no había ninguna norma formal, sino sólo costumbres. Esto cambió recién con la *Ortographia* de 1741 (ver [versión reducida](http://www.rae.es/sites/default/files/Ortografia_RAE_1741_reducida.pdf)), pero la norma impuesta en ese momento era de una *mayusculitis* galopante: además de al principio de oración, párrafo, etc. y después de cada punto, debían ir en mayúscula

> los nombres propios, assi de personas, como de animales en todas sus
>   especies: de árboles, plantas, y metales, ó minerales: de ciencias, y
>   artes: de Reynos, Provincias, Ciudades, Villas, y Lugares: de montes,
>   mares, rios, fuentes, &c. Lo mismo se ha de usar en los sobrenombres,
>   ó apellidos, y en los renombres, ó títulos de autoridad, dignidad, ó
>   fama, y también en los cargos, y empleos honoríficos, y en los oficios
>   públicos de cualquier calidad que sean. También (...) aquellos nombres
>   apelativos, que llaman *colectivos*, porque significan muchas
>   personas, ó cosas juntas, y unidas de algun modo: v. g. Religion,
>   Comunidad, Consejo, Ayuntamiento, Tribunal, Universidad, Colegio,
>   Reyno, Provincia, Ciudad, y assi otros muchos.

P.S.: Esto no explica lo que se ve en el Diccionario de Autoridades pero nos da una cierta base para suponer que quizá las mayúsculas se siguieron utilizando para dar énfasis a algún concepto, quizá especialmente a los colectivos y genéricos.

Comment: Bueno, el _Autoridades_ en realidad se escribió antes que la primera _Ortografía_, se ve que para entonces aún estaban decidiendo qué hacer con la mayusculitis. En todo caso, lo que has citado de dicha _Ortografía_ cuadra bastante, lo único que no explica son las mayúsculas en usos metalingüísticos, pero visto lo visto me parece consecuente. Me ha encantado la respuesta, ¡gracias!

Comment: Que buen termino, *mayusculitis*.  (Vivo con alguien de Alemania.)